# Magento 2.2.7 No such entity with cartId

Tags: magento2

on visiting cart page `www.yoursite.com/checkout/cart` facing this exception.

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
#0 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(149): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', NULL)
#1 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive(NULL)
#2 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('getActive', Array)
#3 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(NULL)
#4 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getActive', Array, Array)
#5 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php(69): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive(NULL)
#6 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider.php(56): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->getList(NULL)
#7 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(287): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider->getImages(NULL)
#8 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#9 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('getConfig', Array)
#10 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#12 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(38): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#13 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(64): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#14 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(98): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getCheckoutConfig()
#15 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/app/design/frontend/Progos/fytm/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml(31): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getSerializedCheckoutConfig()
#16 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/usr/local/ampp...')
#17 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping), '/usr/local/ampp...', Array)
#18 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/usr/local/ampp...')
#19 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart.s...')
#22 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#23 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#24 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#25 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#26 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.summary', false)
#27 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.summary')
#28 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('cart.summary')
#29 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.summary', false)
#30 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('cart.summary', false)
#31 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#32 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#33 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#34 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#35 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false)
#36 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#37 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#38 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#39 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#40 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false)
#41 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#42 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#43 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#44 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#45 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false)
#46 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#47 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#48 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#49 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#50 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false)
#51 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#52 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#53 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#54 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#55 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#56 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#57 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#58 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#59 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#60 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#61 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#62 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#63 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#64 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#65 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#66 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#67 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#69 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#70 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#71 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#73 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#74 /usr/local/ampps/www/fytm/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#75 {main}
```

Comment: Is this   happen for all customer or for a single customer?

Comment: this happens to me too, I think it's related to the session, because if I go back to the store and select other products, I'll go back to the shopping cart and everything works. I'm still looking for a solution ..

Comment: I just found https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7635#issuecomment-267710237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7635#issuecomment-267710237) highlighted by Alfredo has hint for this problem. Actually I was overriding `checkout_cart_index.xml`, and try to moving `cart.summary` after `checkout.cart.form` .
like showing in following image:
[image]
But what I did as follow in my custom module in file `checkout_cart_index.xml`:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="cart.summary" destination="content" after="checkout.cart.form" />
</body></page>
```

Its **wrong**: during move i added destination as `content` which is actually issue mentioned in link ***moving child containers out of `checkout.cart.items` container***.
I moved cart.summary out of `checkout.cart.items` by giving destination as content.

correct xml should be:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.container" after="checkout.cart.form" />
```

Any container in side `checkout.cart.items`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue after adding a new Module.

I disabled the module using

`php bin/magento module:disable MY_MODULE`

And then seen the list of modules to check if this module is disabled:

`php bin/magento module:status`

The module was disabled.

Then clear Magento cache using:

`php bin/magento c:c`

My site was working back.

Comment: This is not the solution you posted here, definitely that custom module have this problem which I highlight.