# Magento 2.4.6 - No such entity with cartId - checkout_cart_index.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, cart, magento2.4

We face the issue that we sometimes get the error in the exception.log:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
#0 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(149): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', NULL)
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive(NULL)
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('getActive', Array)
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(NULL)
#4 /generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getActive', Array, Array)
#5 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php(69): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive(NULL)
#6 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider.php(56): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->getList(NULL)
#7 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(287): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider->getImages(NULL)
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('getConfig', Array)
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#12 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(38): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#13 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(64): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#14 /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(98): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getCheckoutConfig()
#15 /app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml(31): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getSerializedCheckoutConfig()
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/...')
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping), '/...', Array)
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/...')
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#21 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.cart.s...')
#22 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.cart.s...')
#24 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#25 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('checkout.cart.s...', false)
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('cart.summary', false)
#27 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cart.summary')
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('cart.summary')
#29 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cart.summary', false)
#30 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('cart.summary', false)
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#32 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#34 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#35 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false)
#36 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#37 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#38 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#39 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#40 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false)
#41 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#42 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#43 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#44 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#45 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false)
#46 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#47 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#48 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#49 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#50 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false)
#51 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#52 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#53 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#54 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#55 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#56 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#57 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#58 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#59 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#60 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#61 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#62 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#63 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#64 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#65 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#66 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#67 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#68 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#69 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#70 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#71 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#72 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#73 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#74 /index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#75 {main}
```

Actually we are overriding checkout_cart_index.xml that can cause this issue. Because of  try to moving `cart.summary` after `checkout.cart.form`. See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/265089/16894

Our current `checkout_cart_index.xml` looks like this, but we can not find the issue or solve it. What are we missing?

And will this solve the issue or is this issue caused by something else?

**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/checkout.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1px)"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="cart.items" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row cart-items" before="-">
            
                <container name="cart.item.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-8 items-cart" before="-">
                </container>
            
                <container name="cart.totals.block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-lg-4 totals-cart" after="cart.item.block">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="cart.totals.title" before="-" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/text.phtml"/>
                </container>
                
            </container>  
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="page.main.title" destination="cart.item.block" before="-"/>
        <move element="checkout.cart.form" destination="cart.item.block" before="checkout.cart.form"/>
        <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="cart.item.block" before="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        <move element="checkout.cart.order.actions" destination="cart.item.block" after="-"/>
        
        <move element="checkout.cart.crosssell" destination="cart.items" after="-"/>
        
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals.title" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.summary.title" remove="true"/>
        <move element="checkout.cart.container" destination="cart.totals.block" after="checkout.cart.totals.title"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: As some user have pointed, I bet this is not a layout thing. Can you try removing your custom layout from your theme? Does error persist?

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.form" after="checkout.cart.form" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That does remove the entire cart.summary element

Comment: can you please add your extension here ?, so i can check it in my system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error A lot of people facing in the exception.log, everything is working fine but it's difficult to trace this error and fix it, try to apply to try to catch where you can see that this issue will occur or use this solution:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.container" before="checkout.cart.widget" />
```

This will fix your error and if you need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This error doesn't seem anything related to your layout or anything related to frontend. This error occurs when you try to access a cart which already has been deleted.

Please check if there is any process on your site which removes the cart of the customer and check if you are referencing old cart somewhere on the cart page.

Comment: Hmm thanks! Any idea how to find any process which removes the cart of the customer?

Comment: There isn't any concrete method which would help you find the process that removes the cart of the customer. Familiarity with the site itself may help but other than that you could technically delete the cart anywhere. You could try searching for $cart->delete() in custom modules of the codebase start debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.container" before="checkout.cart.widget" />
```

OR

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.container" after="checkout.cart.form" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a super simple cause, no bug and nothing deleting carts. I have this happen on my site when we switch between test and live in the same browser.

The cartid from test doesn't exist in live, obviously. And that causes this exception.

I make sure to use multiple browsers or anonymous sessions to keep things nice and separate. And when we forget, this exception turns up.

It can also happen if the order information in the browser outlives the quote lifetime.

It is a bit sloppy of the Magento code to not have some cleaner failure mode.

Comment: It may not be Magento's fault if you are running the test site on same subdomain. It might be configuration issue with the cookie domain of your test site.

Comment: yes vivek-kumar they have the same cookie domain. But it is still sloppy that someone coming with a cart reference that is gone, whether it is a visitor that last came 3 months ago or us testing, will generate a full blown exception behind the scenes instead of this being detected cleanly. There are a lot of missing such preventive tests in the code base, and also a lot of error messages which don't give the one useful piece of information. Cartid is often not put in these errors, just like item_id or entity_id in other errors. Code submissions improving error messages never get integrated.

Comment: If they have the same cookie domain the cookies for both the sites will be updating information into each others cookies. I don't want to be rude here, but clearly the fault lies in the configuration and not the Magento code base itself in this case. I will say there are many cases where Magento has unintuitive design choices or just weird implementations but this is not one of them.

Comment: Look, I was only giving people an explanation why such things might appear in their log. And I think that the non existence of a cart ID because someone's browser has a non existent cart ID that was since deleted should be a routine error that is caught and ignored, not an exception dump. Because the exception dumps means things were tried - and it also means that an attacker could perhaps do something with thousands of random cartids?

Comment: And it is not an error to have the same cookie domain, it's often the case in configuration management to keep as much identical, it's just something to be aware of if you use the same browser. Simply avoided with multiple browsers or anonymous windows etc. Heck, you can even get errors if you go to front end in same browser as admin session, as some browsers will block things because over max size.

Comment: and in the past on M2 i have had no end of mystery issues when using full subdomain as cookie domain - I suspect there's dozens of tickets here with people tearing their hair out at something.